# A male-to-male cable for the MJ-4PP-9

Tags: components, buying, trrs

I'm building an [Ergodash](https://github.com/omkbd/ErgoDash#parts) which requires a MJ-4PP-9 socket and a matching TRRS cable. I believe I've got the right female with the following dimensions.

[image]

However, all the male-to-male cables I've got have the copper/brass part 15-16 mm long, which doesn't fit the 14.1 mm long MJ-4PP-9. I've tried searching around and all the 3.5mm TRRS cables seem to have about the same size mismatch. I've tried searching for a MJ-4PP-9 cable but got nothing.

How should I search for the matching cable for the MJ-4PP-9?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the MJ-4PP-9 you can use the [PJ-320A](https://keeb.io/products/trrs-jack-3-5mm) TRRS 3.5mm Jack.
On the same page you can find various mating [TRRS cables](https://keeb.io/products/trrs-cable?pr_prod_strat=copurchase&pr_rec_id=1f8629e75&pr_rec_pid=11428282758&pr_ref_pid=10549934214&pr_seq=uniform).

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/bvx6in/cant_find_some_parts_for_ergodash/)